# PDF of distance from the center of a random point in the unit disk

Tags: probability, geometry, probability-theory, probability-distributions, geometric-probability

I found in a certain website (also in an IEEE paper) that the probability function for the distance mentioned in the title is given by the following: $P(d)=2d$, but no one is giving the way to derive such function. Please how to do so?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should specify what is the random way to pick the point.

Answer (score 3):

For the uniform distribution on the unit disk, the probability of observing a distance between $d-\frac{\delta d}{2}$ and $d+\frac{\delta d}{2}$ is the ratio of the area of an annulus with inner radius  $d-\frac{\delta d}{2}$ and an outer radius $d+\frac{\delta d}{2}$ to the area of the whole disk.

The area of the annulus is $= \pi\; 2d\; \delta d + O((\delta d)^2)$

Area of the unit disk is $= \pi$

So Probability of being in the annulus is $= 2d\; \delta d+O((\delta d)^2) \approx P(d) \delta d$, and in the limit as $\delta d \to 0\ $ leaves us with $P(d)=2d$

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the explanation. Why do you still have the O(delta d^2 ) term in the area of the annulus?
Also, why is the probability of being in the annulus approx P(d) *times* delta d?